# What do you call the algebraic structure physical space modeled after?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Physical space is the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ equipped with an inner product (dot product $\cdot$), a bilinear product (cross product $\times$) and is complete (all limits of vector sequences approach some other vector).

Is this a "complete algebra over the Reals with an inner product"?
How about "a Hilbert space with a bilinear product?"

Is there a standard name for this structure? What would you call this structure?

P.S did I miss any other operators/structure on real 3-space that are used to model physical space?

Comment: Maybe you miss between 7 and 22 of the dimensions ... ;)

Comment: We do it with more than one, so the "the" is uncalled for. Asking "what mathematical structures are used to model physical space" would be a perfectly understandable question.

Comment: I guess the question is written in a weird way. Nevertheless I think he only wants a answer whether there is a special name for a Hilbert space with a bilinear product or not.

Comment: Sorry if I worded it weirdly but yeah, I want to know if the structure I stated above has a name. Also I am referring to classical absolute space, not relativistic spacetime or any described by string theory or the like (thought that was obvious).

Comment: This type of space does not need a special name since there is only one space of this type $\ldots$